# Concatenate chunks of equalized duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a bunch of programmatically generated `webm` chunks. Each of them is supposed to be exactly 10 seconds long, and the goal is to concatenate `N` of them to get a continuous `webm` of `N * 10` seconds. The problem is that they always are slightly longer than that, and the error accumulates during the playback, causing discrepancies with other data that depends on exact timestamps.

Each chunk is obtained via `ffmpeg -i audio.wav -i video.webm -map 0 -map 1 -c:a:0 vorbis -c:v:0 copy chunk.webm`, and originally both `audio.wav` and `video.webm` are constructed with the 10 seconds constraint in mind: for `audio.wav` the number of samples is calculated as `sample_rate * TEN_SECONDS`, for `video.webm` the number of frames is calculated as `fps * TEN_SECONDS`. Both are then written to disk and combined by the aforementioned command into `chunk.webm`. Unfortunately `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 chunk.webm` shows that each chunk is *just* slightly longer than expected: 10.003 seconds. I've naively tried to cut them to the desired length by `ffmpeg -i chunk.webm -t 10 output.webm`, but surprisingly it made things worse: 10.008 seconds.

Eventually I wanted to do `ffmpeg concat -i list.txt -map 0 -codec copy all.webm`, where each line of `list.txt` would contain `file chunk_i.webm`, but I am not sure what's the best way to deal with the accumulated error. Is there a widely accepted approach? Could something hacky like 'concatenate one by one, trim to the right duration after each added chunk' work without noticeable problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar considerations apply here as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/42144468/

Comment: I'm willing to drop a frame or a sample here or there (or change the playback speed), would that still not be feasible? The only critical requirement really is the overall duration being as close to `N * 10` as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the framerate. If you are using a fractional framerate such as ntsc 24000/1001 or 30000/1001, encoding to precisely 10.000 seconds could prove more difficult. The same is true of the audio. The default 48khz sample rate would not be exact.

If you encode at a constant frame rate such as 30fps you could then try the following for a 10 second chunk:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.webm -i aud.wav -c:v copy -c:a libvorbis -frames:v 300 -t:a 10.0 output.webm
```

In my testing this got close, but was not exact either. For the accumulated error perhaps try a similar approach

Say you have 10 files in the list and you want the 100 second output.

ffmpeg -f concat -i inputs.txt -c copy -t 100 out100.webm

oddly if i adjusted the time to 99.98 that worked a little better.

ffmpeg just may not be capable of such precision.